# Bootstrap 4 -- How can I add space between overflowed columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Apologies for the awfully worded title. Here is the question I have: I have a row with 4 columns that looks pretty nice on a desktop computer...

[image: looking good on a desktop]

...but looks really bad on mobile, because there is no margin between the columns that overflowed.

[image: looking mediocre on mobile]

Here is how I wrote each column:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <h1><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i></h1>
        <h4>Boston, Massachusetts, United States of America</h4>
    </div>
```

Short of writing entirely separate grids for each screen size, is there any way to make the overflowed columns look nice? I'd like some white space between each column.

Here is the full CSS code, in case it helps.

```
/* this CSS sheet applies to my home page 
I am using a color scheme from this fantastic article
https://www.canva.com/learn/100-color-combinations/
#375e97  rgba(55, 94, 151, 0.2) sky -- a deep blue
#fb6542  rgba(251,101,66,1) sunset -- a salmon color
#ffbb00  rgba(255,187,0,1) sunflower -- yellow
#3f681c  rgba(63,104,28,1) grass -- dark green
*/
body{
    font-size: 1rem;
    color:#3f681c;
    font-family: Kalam, sans-serif;
    background-color: #e2E8e4;
    line-height: 1.5;

}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

hr{
    height:0.08rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    background-color: #3f681c;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.row__marginb{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.jumbotron{
    line-height: 2;
}

#mainJumbotron{
    height: 55vh;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:radial-gradient(rgba(55, 94, 151, 0.2), rgba(51, 107, 135, 0.0)), url("/static/home/img/august.jpg");
    border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 92%, 92% 100%, 8% 100%, 0% 92%);
}

.nameTitle{
    font-family: Pacifico, serif;
    color:#fdf6f6;
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.mainSubtitle{
    font-family: Patua One, serif;
    color:#fdf6f6;
    font-size:1.5rem;
}

.profilepic{
    border-radius: 3rem;
}

.btn-socialmedia:link,.btn-socialmedia:visited{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:5rem;
    width:5rem;
    padding:0.4rem 0.6rem 0.3rem 0.6rem;
    border-radius:0.5rem;
    background-color: #3f681c;
    color:#fdf6f6;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0rem;
    transition: bottom 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-socialmedia:hover{
    color:#fdf6f6ec;
    bottom:0.2rem;
}

.btn-socialmedia:active{
    bottom:0.1rem;
}

.footer{
    color:#fdf6f6;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(55, 94, 151, 1), rgb(10, 96, 139));
    padding-top:1rem;
    clip-path: polygon(8% 0%, 92% 0%, 100% 92%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 92%);
}

.flagImage{
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 2.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML

```
    <div class="row text-center row__marginb">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-scroll"></i></h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h5><a class="text-success" href="{% static 'home/handouts/JimmySbordone_Resume.pdf' %}"
                            download>Resume</a> </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img class="flagImage" src="{% static 'home/img/america.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h5><a class="text-success" href="{% static 'home/handouts/JimmySbordone_CV.pdf' %}" download>CV</a>
                    </h5>

                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img class="flagImage" src="{% static 'home/img/america.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h5><a class="text-success" href="{% static 'home/handouts/JimmySbordone_CV_italiano.doc' %}"
                            download> CV</a> </h5>

                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img class="flagImage" src="{% static 'home/img/italy.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-laptop"></i> </h1>
            <a class="btn-socialmedia" href="https://www.facebook.com/jsbordone" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a class="btn-socialmedia" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jimmy-sbordone-aaa806128/" target="_blank"><i
                    class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            <a class="btn-socialmedia" href="https://github.com/JimmySbordoneJr" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> </h1>
            <h3>jsbordon@bu.edu</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i></h1>
            <h4>Boston, Massachusetts, United States of America</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the margin classes, for example

`mt-xs-2` for .5rem top margin for the xs media query
or just `mt-1` or `mt-2` for any media query.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mt-xs-2">
       <h1><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i></h1>
        <h4>Boston, Massachusetts, United States of America</h4>
 </div>
```

more info in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using where the max-width is the size of the screen

```
@media only screen and (max-width:435px){
  .col-sm-6{
  padding:1px;
  margin:1px;
 }
}
```